# Save the generated HTML code to a file

Tags: php, html

I create an application that dynamically generates certain structures in Javascript and sends them to PHP in the resulting form. Generator is practically finished, although I have trouble writing the generated HTML code to a file. I have this PHP code and i want save generated HTML code to file. If i use this code:

```
$fp = fopen('plik.html', 'w');
fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('./generate.php'));
fclose($fp);
```

I get this file content:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',0); 

    @$tytul = $_POST['k-title'];
    @$opis = $_POST['k-desc'];

    $fp = fopen('plik.html', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('./generate.php'));
    fclose($fp);

    // albo dla PHP 5:

    file_put_contents('plik.html', file_get_contents('./generate.php'));

    /* echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>"; */

    if ($tytul == '' || $opis == '') {

        echo '<div><p>Błąd</p><p>Uzupełnij wszystkie pola generatora!</p>';

    } else {


        echo '<div style="max-width: 1050px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">';
        echo '<div style="padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">';
        echo '<p style="font-size: 30px; text-align: center;">'.$tytul.'</p>';
        echo '<p style="font-size: 15px; text-align: justify;">'.$opis.'</p>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: #eee; font-weight: 200; line-height: 0.92em; padding: 23px 0; font-size: 30px;">Specyfikacja techniczna</div>';
        echo '<table style="font-size: 14px; border: none; border-top: 1px solid #dbdbdb; border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb; width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5px"><tbody>';

        $cechy = array_combine($_POST['cecha'], $_POST['cecha-opis']);
        foreach($cechy as $klucz => $wartosc) {

            echo '<tr><td style="padding: 3px 10px; text-align: right; border-right: 1px solid #dbdbdb;" width="50%">';
            echo $klucz;
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td style="padding: 3px 10px; text-align: left;" width="50%">';
            echo $wartosc;
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }

        echo '</tbody></table>';

        $prezentacje = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['pwidth']); $i++) {
        $prezentacja = array();
        $prezentacja['pwidth'] = $_POST['pwidth'][$i];
        $prezentacja['pheight'] = $_POST['pheight'][$i];
        $prezentacja['psource'] = $_POST['psource'][$i];
        array_push($prezentacje, $prezentacja);
        }

        foreach($prezentacje as $p) {
        echo '<img style="width: ' . $p['pwidth'] . 'px; height: ' . $p['pheight'] . 'px;" src="' . $p['psource'] . '" />';
        }

        echo '<div style="clear: both;"></div>';

        $section = array();
        for($a = 0; $a < count($_POST['sectionwidth']); $a++) {
        $sesfull = array();
        $sesfull['sectionwidth'] = $_POST['sectionwidth'][$a];
        $sesfull['sectionheight'] = $_POST['sectionheight'][$a];
        $sesfull['bg'] = $_POST['bg'][$a];
        $sesfull['sectioncolor'] = $_POST['sectioncolor'][$a];
        $sesfull['inputwidth'] = $_POST['inputwidth'][$a];
        array_push($section, $sesfull);
        }

        foreach ($_POST['section'] as $sekcja) {
            echo '<div style="margin: 0; float: left; width: '.$sekcja['sectionwidth'].'px; height: '.$sekcja['sectionheight'].'px; background: #'.$sekcja['bg'].'; color: #'.$sekcja['sectioncolor'].';">';
            foreach ($sekcja['input'] as $input) {
                echo '<p style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: '.$input['inputwidth'].'px;">'.$input['inputtext'].'</p>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }

        echo '<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: #eee; font-weight: 200; line-height: 0.92em; padding: 23px 0; font-size: 30px; clear: both;">Galeria zdjęć</div>';

        $gallery = array_combine($_POST['srcphoto'], $_POST['descphoto']);
        foreach ($gallery as $source => $alt) {
        echo '<img style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 25px;" src="'.$source.'" alt="'.$alt.'" /></img>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        }
```

Is it possible to save only the generated HTML code by a PHP script while previewing the generated content?

**Update #2:**

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',0); 

    $tytul = $_POST['k-title'];
    $opis = $_POST['k-desc'];

    ob_start(); ?>

        <div style="max-width: 1050px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <div style="padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
        <p style="font-size: 30px; text-align: center;"><?php echo $tytul; ?></p>
        <p style="font-size: 15px; text-align: justify;"><?php echo $opis; ?></p>
        </div>

        <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: #eee; font-weight: 200; line-height: 0.92em; padding: 23px 0; font-size: 30px;">Specyfikacja techniczna</div>
        <table style="font-size: 14px; border: none; border-top: 1px solid #dbdbdb; border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb; width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5px"><tbody>

        <?php 
        $cechy = array_combine($_POST['cecha'], $_POST['cecha-opis']);
        foreach($cechy as $klucz => $wartosc) {

        ?>
            <tr><td style="padding: 3px 10px; text-align: right; border-right: 1px solid #dbdbdb;" width="50%">
            <?php echo $klucz ?>
            </td>
            <td style="padding: 3px 10px; text-align: left;" width="50%">
            <?php echo $wartosc; ?>
            </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

        </tbody></table>

        <?php
        $prezentacje = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['pwidth']); $i++) {
        $prezentacja = array();
        $prezentacja['pwidth'] = $_POST['pwidth'][$i];
        $prezentacja['pheight'] = $_POST['pheight'][$i];
        $prezentacja['psource'] = $_POST['psource'][$i];
        array_push($prezentacje, $prezentacja);
        }
        foreach($prezentacje as $p) {

        ?>
        <img style="float: left; max-width: 100%; width:<?php echo $p['pwidth']; ?>px; height: <?php echo $p['pheight']; ?>px;" src="<?php echo $p['psource']; ?>" />
        <?php
        }
        ?>

        <div style="clear: both;"></div>

        <?php 
        $section = array();
        for($a = 0; $a < count($_POST['sectionwidth']); $a++) {
        $sesfull = array();
        $sesfull['sectionwidth'] = $_POST['sectionwidth'][$a];
        $sesfull['sectionheight'] = $_POST['sectionheight'][$a];
        $sesfull['bg'] = $_POST['bg'][$a];
        $sesfull['sectioncolor'] = $_POST['sectioncolor'][$a];
        $sesfull['inputwidth'] = $_POST['inputwidth'][$a];
        array_push($section, $sesfull);
        }

        foreach ($_POST['section'] as $sekcja) {

        ?>

            <div style="margin: 0; float: left; width: <?php echo $sekcja['sectionwidth']; ?>px; height: <?php echo $sekcja['sectionheight']; ?>px; background: #<?php echo $sekcja['bg']; ?>; color: #<?php echo $sekcja['sectioncolor']; ?>;">
            <?php 
            foreach ($sekcja['input'] as $input) {
            ?>
                <p style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: <?php echo $input['inputwidth']; ?>px"> <?php echo $input['inputtext']; ?> </p>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
        <?php 
        } 
        ?>

        <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: #eee; font-weight: 200; line-height: 0.92em; padding: 23px 0; font-size: 30px; clear: both;">Galeria zdjęć</div>
        <?php 
        $gallery = array_combine($_POST['srcphoto'], $_POST['descphoto']);
        foreach ($gallery as $source => $alt) {

        ?>
        <img style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 25px;" src="<?php echo $source; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" /></img>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>

<?php
$szablon = ob_end_flush();
echo $szablon;
$fp = fopen('plik.html', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $szablon);
fclose($fp);
file_put_contents('plik.html', $szablon);
?>
```

Comment: You are using  `@` operator wrong (aside from the fact that using is is usually wrong in general in first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use output buffering in your script (http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

Something like...

```
    ob_start();
    echo 'Some html';
    $text = ob_get_flush();
    echo "Content is:".$text;
```

will output

```
Content is:Some html
```

**Update**:
If you wanted to capture all of the output which your generating, the `ob_start();` starts the buffering (where you have it in your example is fine), then when you've generated what your after (so for example )...

```
</tbody></table>
<?php
$content = ob_get_flush();
fwrite($fp, $content);
```

Comment: Good idea, but i don't know how can i add elements in foreach to ob_start

Look to edit topic

Comment: You could put the ob_start before the foreach?  Or you could store the output in an array ( `$text[] = ob_get_flush()` )

Comment: Can you show me, how can i do this e.g code example in edit?

Comment: I'm also not sure if you need to overwrite the file contents in $fp or add to it.  So you may want to adjust this according to what you need.

Comment: More precisely, this is the line

https://pastebin.com/Axd2gRtm

How to include this in ob_start to work?

Comment: If you consider ob_start/ob_get as a way of building up a string, but instead of you explicitly creating it, it's all of the text you `echo` out.  So using this idea, you can set it up how you need. Put the start at the just after the `foreach()` and the ob_get before the last `}` if that's the output you want to capture.

Comment: I have one more problem - ob_start works beautiful, but after save to file i get value = "1", nothing more - wtf?

Comment: Can you add to your updated answer the code you currently have.

Comment: Remove all but the first ob_start, you could do it block by block, but do it one chunk.  ob_get_flush takes the input up till the last ob_start so it will only fetch the last bit.

Comment: Just try and comment out all but the first ob_start, see how that works.

Comment: Did I understand correctly? I have to move everything to the first ob_start and delete other?

Comment: Remove all ob_start calls except the one after `$opis = $_POST['k-desc'];`

Comment: I did it, but it only saves one bit

Answer (score -1):

You will have to get the generated HTML by accessing your generate.php script through a web server (e.g. http://localhost/generate.php, depending on where your code is located).

```
file_get_contents('http://localhost/generate.php');
```